# Recursion for Church encoding of equality

Tags: recursion, coq, equality, church-encoding

For the Church encoding `N` of positive integers, one can define a recursion principle `nat_rec` :

```
Definition N : Type :=
forall (X:Type), X->(X->X)->X.

Definition nat_rec (z:N)(s:N->N)(n:N) : N :=
n N z s.
```

What is the recursion principle `equal_rec` for the following Church encoding `equal` of equality?

```
Definition equal (x:A) : A->Type :=
fun x' => forall (P:A->Type), P x -> P x'.

Definition equal_rec (* ... *)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the case of natural numbers, the recursion principle is simply an eta expansion:

```
Definition equal (A:Type) (x:A) : A->Type :=
  fun x' => forall (P:A->Type), P x -> P x'.

Definition equal_rec (A:Type) (x y : A) (e : equal x y) (P : A -> Type) : P x -> P y :=
  e P.
```

Comment: This looks pretty useless, isn't it? Can it be used to prove symmetry, transitivity or congruence of equality?

Comment: It cannot, because of universe issues. But you can replace `Type` by `Prop` everywhere, and it should work.

Comment: @Bob since you are interested in proofs, for proofs the recursor is not enough. You need a thing called "dependent eliminator", and for example for naturals the dependent eliminator is not definable for the Church encoding because the fact that there are no non-standard inhabitants besides chains of S and Z is not provable. That's why we need explicit inductive types in coq. You can see the issue by proving that for the chucrch encoding for any boolean x either x == true or x == false. There are some works on how the encoding can be amended though to get induction, if I remember correctly